# sys.exit() not exiting in python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I have a python2 program which uses `socket` and `SocketServer`. it basically consists of some clients, that can connect with each other.Each Client also has their own `Thread` which is implemented using `threading.Thread` and run in `daemon` mode. Now my problem is that when i call `sys.exit()` the program doesn't exit.I also (try to) close all open sockets before `sys.exit()` call.I also use `socket.makefile()` in the program, however I call `close` on all of the opened files right after I read from them.What could be the potential causes if `sys.exit()` not exiting?

Here's the code, the application is supposed to represent a graph of nodes,
each node will contain an Edge to another node if we call `initiateConnection` on the first node with the address of the second one.Since the Edges are undirected I want both sides of the socket to be handled by the same `RequestHandler`.See notes above `Client.initiateConnection`.

```
import socket
import SocketServer
import select
import sys
import threading

class Client(SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer):

    """Attributes:
    neighbours: connections to neighbours
    n_addresses: addresses of Neighbours
    requests: Number of Requests Sent
    processed_requests:{}
    id: this client's id
    """

    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, id):
        self.neighbours = []
        self.n_addresses = []
        self.requests = 0
        self.processed_requests = {}
        self.id = id
        SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass)

    def initiateConnection(self, address):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect(address)
        self.neighbours.append(s)
        self.n_addresses.append(s.getpeername())
        self.addConnection(s, address)
        # check if the given port, and the connected one match
        if address[1] != s.getpeername()[1]:
            raise Exception(address, s.getpeername())

    """ this method is based on the _handle_request_no_block method on the base server
    we will add the connection created by this node i.e: this node is the client for that
    particular connection, to the list of connections handled by this server, i.e: view it as a server connection
    """
    #This method is supposed to add the request first instantiated by
    # the Client instance itself, to the requests the ThreadingTCPServer manages (creates a seperate thread for it and etc.)
    # Maybe there's something else I have to do, so that the ThreadingTCPServer closes this connection properly?
    def addConnection(self, request, address):
        if self.verify_request(request, address):
            try:
                self.process_request(request, address)
            except:
                self.handle_error(request, address)
                self.shutdown_request(request)

    def addNeighbour(self, s):
        self.neighbours.append(s)
        self.n_addresses.append(s.getpeername())

    def server_close(self):
        print("{}: closing neighbours".format(self.id))
        for c in self.neighbours:
            print("{}: closing {}".format(c.getpeername()))
            c.close()
        print("{}: closed all neighbours".format(self.id))
        SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer.server_close(self)


class RequestHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):

    GET_NEIGHBOURS="1"
    EOR="EOR"
    # the below function means someone is trying to initiate
    # connection, since it will be handled in it's own thread
    # we will initiate a loop and wait for a request.
    def handle(self):
        self.server.addNeighbour(self.request)
        while True:
            lines = []
            select.select([self.rfile], [], [])
            print("{}: got request from {}".format(self.server.id, self.request.getpeername()))
            while True:
                line = self.rfile.readline().strip()
                print("line read:\n{}".format(line))
                if line == RequestHandler.EOR:
                    break
                elif not bool(line):
                    continue
                lines.append(line)
            print("{}: all request lines read:\n{}".format(self.server.id, lines))
            # we have a complete request now process it
            if lines[1] == self.GET_NEIGHBOURS:
                print("{}: request was of type    get_neighbours".format(self.server.id))
                data = self.processNeighbours(lines)
                self.request.sendall("{}\n".format(data))
                print("{}: data sent to {}".format(self.server.id, self.request.getpeername()))

class UnknownRequestCode(Exception): pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    def output(s):
        print(s)
    def getLine():
        return sys.stdin.readline()

    address = ('', 0)
    clients = {}
    addresses = {}
    while True:
        print("commands:\nclose: exit\nnew: make a new client, will prompt for a client id\nshow: show a clients neighbours, will prompt for a client's id\nconnect: will connect a client to another one, will prompt for the ids")
        i = getLine().strip()
        if i == "close":
            for c in clients.values():
                c.shutdown()
            print("everything shut down")
            sys.exit()
        if i == "new":
            i = getLine(). strip()
            client = Client(address, RequestHandler, i)
            clients[i] = client
            a = client.server_address
            addresses[i] = a
            output(a)
            t = threading.Thread(target=client.serve_forever)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
        elif i == "show":
            i = getLine().strip()
            c = clients[i]
            o = c.startSearch()
            #output(o)       
        elif i == "connect":
            i = getLine().strip()
            c = clients[i]
            i = getLine().strip()
            a = addresses[i]
            print("{}".format(a))
            c.initiateConnection(a)
```

**UPDATE**: I have identified the (rather obvious) problem, the handle method never exits the loop since the nodes are always supposed to get connected, and wait for each other's request.But I can not check program termination since it gets stuck before the `select.select` call.How can I fix that?

Comment: Do you have a try statement surrounding the call? You do realize that a system exit is basically an intentionally thrown error?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi No there is not, and yes I do.

Comment: @PaulRooney I will post some code shortly the problem is when I start to connect two Nodes i.e: `Client.initiateConnection` if I don't call that, it will exit, even if multiple `Client`s are instantiated

Comment: @PaulRooney it's not actually the `initiateConnection` that's causing the problem, it's the request handler's handler method.

Answer (score 0):

a python program ends when all threads exit. i think your thread functions do not return which means the program will wait for them to return even if you call exit().

if that is the case (and i really think it is), then a simple solution is to have a global 'running' flag = True:

```
running = True
```

and inside each thread, you create a loop that checks this flag before running:

```
#thread function
def thread_function ():
    #loop checks the flag
    while running:
        pass    #write loop code here
    #if running turns to false, then you will be here
    pass    #write clean up code here
```

hope it helps

Comment: I thought it would be, but the ones I'm creating cause no problem, and the others which are created by the SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer are terminated when call `server.shutdown`. I've added some code.

Comment: Turns out you were right, please take a look at the `RequestHandlers`'s handle method and the note added at the end.

Comment: in the handle method, you are using select without timeout:
`select.select([self.rfile], [], [])`

this means "wait forever until the file is ready for reading". what happens if the file is never ready for reading? you function will block forever.

you should use a timeout like this:
`select.select([self.rfile], [], [], 0.5)`

like this, your function will block for half a second then returns with empty lists unless the file is ready for reading. that way, you can process other things (like check flags) continuesly.

I did not look at everything in the code. Not sure if other things are ok.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `RequestHandler.handle` runs in an infinite loop, and waits for request from the other side and vice versa, we must terminate it when the main process exits.The key was in `SocketServer.ThreadingMixin.daemon_threads` which must be set to true, so that the created threads that will eventually run the handle method will be terminated upon exit.